# read rgb values stored in csv file seperated by comma deliminator

Tags: java, csv, colors, rgb

I am using file reader to read the csv file, the second column of the csv file is an rgb value such as rgb(255,255,255) but the columns in the csv file is separate by commas. If I use comma deliminator, it will read like "rgb(255," so how do I read the whole rgb value, the code is pasted below. Thanks!

```
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(todoTaskFile);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

        int columnIndex = 1;
        String line;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.trim().length() != 0) {
                String[] dataFields = line.split(",");
                //System.out.println(dataFields[0]+dataFields[1]);
                if (!taskCount.containsKey(dataFields[columnIndex])) {
                    taskCount.put(dataFields[columnIndex], 1);
                } else {
                    int oldCount = taskCount.get(dataFields[columnIndex]);
                    taskCount.put(dataFields[columnIndex],oldCount + 1);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest not to use custom methods to parse CSV input. There are special libraries that do it for you.

@Ashraful Islam posted a good way to parse the value from a "cell" (I reused it), but getting this "cell" raw value must be done in a different way. This sketch shows how to do it using `apache.commons.csv` library.

```
package csvparsing;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GetRGBFromCSV {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Reader in = new FileReader(GetRGBFromCSV.class.getClassLoader().getResource("sample.csv").getFile());
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(in); // remove ".withFirstRecordAsHeader()"
        for (CSVRecord record : records) {
            String color = record.get("Color"); // use ".get(1)" to get value from second column if there's no header in csv file
            System.out.println(color);

            Pattern RGB_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("rgb\\((\\d{1,3}),(\\d{1,3}),(\\d{1,3})\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            Matcher m = RGB_PATTERN.matcher(color);
            if (m.find()) {
                Integer red = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
                Integer green = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
                Integer blue = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
                System.out.println(red + " " + green + " " + blue);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is a custom valid CSV input which would probably make regex-based solutions behave unexpectedly:

```
Name,Color
"something","rgb(100,200,10)"
"something else","rgb(10,20,30)"
"not the value rgb(1,2,3) you are interested in","rgb(10,20,30)"
```

There are lots of options which you might forget to take into account when you write your custom parser: quoted and unquoted strings, delimiter within quotes, escaped quotes within quotes, different delimiters (`,` or `;`), multiple columns etc. Third-party csv parser would take care about those things for you. You shouldn't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
    line = "rgb(25,255,255)";
    line = line.replace(")", "");
    line = line.replace("rgb(", "");
    String[] vals = line.split(",");
```

cast the values in vals to Integer and then you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this :

```
Pattern RGB_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("rgb\\((\\d{1,3}),(\\d{1,3}),(\\d{1,3})\\)");

String line = "rgb(25,255,255)";
Matcher m = RGB_PATTERN.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

Here

```
\\d{1,3}   => match 1 to 3 length digit
(\\d{1,3}) => match 1 to 3 length digit and stored the match
```

Though `(` or `)` are meta character we have to escape it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works by using your method. But how do I call group() to plot the pie chart by using the rgb value to style the pie chart? Thanks! I was using a controller and call the read method and plot method in the initialize(), the only thing i did wrong is the color of the pie chart.

Comment: If you want to get the red color use `m.group(1)`, for green use `m.group(2)`, for blue use `m.group(3)`

Comment: yea, I tried to call m.group(); in the initialize()method to style the pie chart,  but it won't recognize the m.group().